# Is there a bug in Delphi's TCanvas?

Tags: delphi, graphics

I'm just going to throw this out here to get some feedback on it, what I call "[remember to count zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_by_one)" (thanks Andreas Rejbrand for the link. It turned out it's called the "off by one problem") when working with pixels. What do I mean by remember to count zero? Well, if you implement a routine that needs to calculate the number of pixels involved in a rectangular operation (e.g `FillRect` or `CopyRect`) you must remember that zero (0,0) is a pixel to. But the rule of regarding zero as a pixel rather than a number of no value, only seem to come into play with coordinates involving < = 0 values. Take this example:

```pascal
mRect:=Rect(0,0,10,10);
mRectWidth:=mRect.right-mRect.left; // returns 10 - 0 = 10
```

See the problem? the rectangle actually defines, in pixel-operation terms, a region stretching from position 0,0 to position 10, 10. Which is actually 11 steps long, not ten (for x:=0 to 10 is actually 11 steps). To make up for the lost pixel (zero has no mass and vanish when you move it into positive or negative space. The Pythagorean theorem of God I seem to remember) most people just add 1 to the final result, like this:

```pascal
function getRectWidth(const aRect:TRect):Integer;
Begin
  result:=(aRect.right-aRect.left) +1;
End;
```

Now this works, in fact it works so well that 90% of all graphics libraries use this as their technique to calculate the width and height of a rectangle. But just like the mighty hero Achillees it has a weak spot, namely that empty rectangles return as having the mass of 1 (It can also create all sorts of funny AV's if you use it with a blitter).

```pascal
mRect:=Rect(0,0,0,0);
mRectWidth:=(mRect.right-mRect.left) + 1;
```

Which roughly equates to `0 – 0 = 0 : +1 = 1`, which means that a pixel will be rendered if you don't look out for the blind-spot. What puzzles me is that, Delphi XE actually seems to have a clipping problem (?), or at least a contradiction in terms. Because you actually lose one pixel at the bottom and to the utmost right if you draw to it. Shouldn't `ClientRect` return the full drawing scope from the first pixel to the last? – yet if you try this:

```pascal
mRect:=getClientRect;
MoveTo(mRect.left,mRect.Bottom);
LineTo(mRect.right,mRect.bottom);
```

You won't see a thing! Because Delphi clips the final pixel (by mistake?). It just seems curious that when you ask for the `clientrect`, that you manually have to adjust it?

I have coded my own graphics libraries from scratch (for fast dib access and offscreen rendering, nothing to do with this particular case), so I have worked inside these methods for a long time now. There is always something new to learn when it comes to coding, but no one can tell me that there isn't a blind spot at work in this material.

When I compared how the VCL does things to other libraries, especially those written in C# I also noticed that a lot of them did like me - and made sure that a `clientrect` IS the full scope of the region you can work with. And they also took height for the "blind spot" when blitting outside the clipregion and working with overlapping rectangles.

**The case of the blindspot**

Let us say you are copying a rectangle from one bitmap to the other. The target for your blit is `Rect(-10,-10,10,10)`. In order to correctly "clip" the target here, so you don't get an access violation for writing outside your memory buffer, you have to calculate the distance between X1/Y1 and your `cliprect` (here taken to be `0,0,Width-1,Height-1`).

This gives you an offset that must be added to the target rectangle and the source rectangle. Otherwise you will write outside the buffer but also read from the wrong place in the source buffer.

Now, it depends on how you implement this off course. But there are plenty of libraries out there that don't take zero into account. The blind-spot occurs when X1 and X2 has the same value, but x1 is negative. Because people usually write: `mOffset:= x2 - abs(x1)`. Which in our case becomes 10-10 = 0. And as long as the `cliprect` is set to 0,0 it will work just fine. But the moment your `cliprect` moves into positive space - you will be off by one pixel. And if you automatically Inc the values in your `getRectWidth` (e.g `mWidth:=aRect.right-aRect.left +1`) - you will be off by 2 pixels depending on the source rectangle (I know, this is major boring stuff).

Under C# on the Mac, using GTK# and also the native MonoMac bindings - the `clientrect` is absolute. Meaning that you can draw to `mRect.bottom` or `mRect.right` and have visible results. Hence I found it curious that my favorite language and toolkit, Delphi, we always have to do manually adjust the `clientrect` of every `ownerdrawn` or custom control when we work with it.

Comment: This is only a particular instance of the well-known [off by one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_by_one) problem.

Comment: the zero or less than part of your question is particularly puzzling

Comment: @David: Well the question is pretty obvious (+1). But getting to the end of the story, picking up your eyes from the table and recover from the made assumptions and stated _facts_ is a whole other thing (-1).

Comment: Added info about the blind-spot to make it more clear what I mean. It is a real phenomenon as pointed out by Andreas and when working with blitting and clipping you see it clearly. The code for intersectRect is a perfect example, as the coder clearly takes height for it.

Comment: Try to remember that TCanvas is just a thin OO wrapper for the GDI Canvas.

Comment: TCanvas is not the problem, I have worked a lot with GDI over the years. The problem is how the VCL works with offsets and regions, and also (once were at it) how it renders each control. It creates a temp device-context per draw (hopefully this has been changed in XE), which is incredibly slow compared to other frameworks. It also makes it hard(er) to handle segmented updates (e.g dirty rectangles) since you have to redraw the whole thing no matter what. And dont get me started on double buffering :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how GDI works and Delphi's `TCanvas` merely mirrors the underlying framework.

For example, consider [`LineTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145029%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> The **LineTo** function draws a line from the current position up to, but not including, the specified point.

Or [`FillRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162719%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> The **FillRect** function fills a rectangle by using the specified brush. This function includes the left and top borders, but excludes the right and bottom borders of the rectangle.

Or [`Rectangle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162898%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> The rectangle that is drawn excludes the bottom and right edges.

And so on and so on.

Consider now the API function [`GetWindowRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519%28VS.85%29.aspx).

> Retrieves the dimensions of the bounding rectangle of the specified window. The dimensions are given in screen coordinates that are relative to the upper-left corner of the screen.

The `bottom` and `right` values in the returned `RECT` are 1 pixel beyond the boundary of the window. So the width of the window really is `width = right-left` and likewise for the height.  It is my guess that the convention was chosen so that this equality holds.

The behaviour you report is not a bug in Delphi's `TCanvas` code — the code works correctly and exactly as designed.

By far the best approach for developers working with Windows UI is to follow the same conventions.  Attempting to adopt your own different conventions will simply lead to confusion and bugs.

Comment: The confusion comes when working with different implementation of native FillRect methods. I have seen maybe 3 different variations on this theme. I avoided the problem by filling scanlines from mRect.left to mRect.right - but two of the others first calculated width/height - and got it wrong. No blame in this ofcourse, but I was just curious. There is always theory vs. hands-on experience at work, and this isnt exactly something I'm losing sleep over :)

Answer (score 9):

I am terribly sorry for your effort writing a complete library for this *phenomenon*, but you are totally wrong.

For example, your code should be like:

```
mRect := getClientRect;
MoveTo(mRect.left, mRect.Bottom - 1);
LineTo(mRect.right - 1, mRect.bottom - 1);
```

Always take into account that routines like `FillRect()` do nothing on `X = Rect.Right` nor `Y = Rect.Bottom`. They all draw until `Right - 1` and `Bottom - 1`. That's how it should be: for a button with `Left = 10` and `Width = 10`, de rightmost pixel is found at `X = 19`, not `X = 20`.

Maybe it ís confusing, but you can easily visualize this on a paper square block.

Comment: I didnt write a library for this phenomenon (that would be eh, mad) I wrote it for better speed and direct DIB access :) And I didnt post this here for the obvious solutions, like I stated - most people take height for it - but i was just curious about the clipregion used in Delphi. You would expect clientrect to represent the whole area of a custom control or surface - yet you always have to do a -1 on the bottom-most and right-most offsets.

Comment: Clipping in Delphi occurs rarely automatically when drawing by yourself. You cán use/drive it, but it is always cheaper to draw only there where you need to.

Comment: Actually Delphi clips does handle overall clipping for you. If you look at the VCL code for TCustomControl and TWinControl, Delphi creates a temp device-context per rendering of a control surface. Adjusting clientrect so that it contains the full drawing area is just a matter or doing a -1 or right and bottom in the vcl code. As opposed to us having to do it every single time :)

Comment: Yes, but only if we take height for zero. So a height of 100 means you can write from 0..99. Wouldnt it make more sense in a fast drawing system to then give you a rect of (0,0,99,99) when you ask for the clientrect? And that when you draw from 0,99 - 99,99 that it actually shows up?

Comment: @Jon Whilst it is an interesting argument as to which convention is better, the Windows convention will never change and your best strategy is to embrace it. If you try to mix conventions then you will have a world of pain. You simply need to learn the rules and stick to them.

Comment: Knowing the rules and accepting the rules are different things, but yeah. I think we can let this one slide now. But.. had i not posted it I wouldnt have learned that it was actually called the "off by one" problem. And now others will find that to when they search. So it wasnt a complete waste of time :)